# Laravel 4 Href returns with baseurl

Tags: php, laravel-4

href will come with baseurl inside it, src wont.

How do i not let href contain baseurl? it's added automatically. I tried to echo it , it doesnt show baseurl unless it's inside href.

Anyway i can display just the raw url? $item->link has it's own baseurl already.

Code

```
<a target="_blank" href="{{$item->link}}"><img src="{{$item->img_link}}" /></a>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Does $item->link has "http://" included in it? I think if it has http:// it will take just the raw URL, instead of relative URL.

Comment: Yes, I confirmed. just prepend "http://" before $item->link and it will link to the raw url $item->link refers to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is to do with how href attribute works, rather than anything else.

If the link given in the href attribute doesn't have "http://", it always links to baseURL/HREF_ATTRIBUTE, but if it has "http://", it takes HREF_ATTRIBUTE as the complete URL.

you can try it out separately by creating an index.php file, inside test folder and putting below line

```
<a target="_blank" href="www.xyz.com">Hello</a>
```

This will refer to localhost/test/www.xyz.com

But if you change it as

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.xyz.com">Hello</a>
```

This will refer to www.xyz.com.